# Glass behaving like mirror issues

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

My brown cosmetic bottle seems good on view port, but as soon as  I render it on Cycles it becomes like chrome

Viewport

[image]

Rendered

[image]

[Original file on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p6jQeLitVyGkfwE20_ZGiUHqDtAD7tyg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What blender version are you using?

Comment: First image looks like it's reflecting an Enviroment and the second image look like there is no enviroment to refflect except for the white plane, did you add an HDRI for you Render? viewport shader's HDRI are not visible on the final render, you need to add one to the World shader.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your objects:

- Your floor has overlapping faces, it creates Z fighting and it will render black, merge the vertices:

[image]

- You've assigned a bad material to the inner faces of your bottle, give them the good material:

[image]

- The green color of the *Glass* node is too dark, enlight it:

[image]

- The IOR value of your glass object is much too high, bring it back to about 1.5:

[image]